# Add description to category collection

Tags: magento-1.9, category, ce-1.9.2.0

To get all categories I'm using this:

```
$categories = $this->helper('catalog/category')->getStoreCategories(false, true);
```

How I can add description to this collection?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried displaying the description as in done in Magentos core theme view template.

```
   <?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
        <div class="category-description std">
            <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($category, $_description, 'description') ?>
        </div>
   <?php endif; ?>
```

You might have to modify this if you are trying to get the description outside of a category page, the below should work outside of a category page.

```
   <?php if($category()->getDescription()): ?>
        <div class="category-description std">
            <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($category, $_description, 'description') ?>
        </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Also note if you are doing this outside the category template make sure you are loading the full category model.

Just load the attributes you need to display.

As you are loading all categories use the below and just load the attributes you need to use:

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
')->addFieldToSelect(array('name', 'description', 'url', 'id', 'url_key')
->addAttributeToSelect('is_active');
```

Comment: Actually I did exactly same, but since "$category()->getDescription()" returns nothing It does not pass the if statement

Comment: Strange how are you loading the category

Comment: $categories = $this->helper('catalog/category')->getStoreCategories(false, true); and then a loop foreach ($categories as $category) {...} It works for name but not description

Comment: in your loop can you try loading the full category model $category_model=Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId()); and then echo $category_model->getDescription(); does that work?

Comment: no probs ill update my answer with the code that worked for you :)

Comment: But it does not load the image in description ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31010/discussion-between-bobadevv-and-zinat).

Comment: Please don't do that. Loading the entire model is extremely resource intensive, loading it in a loop is a time bomb. You need to add the description to the collection you are loading

Comment: Very true point taken i've update my answer loading full category object is a bit sloppy

Comment: This did not work for me Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId())->addFieldToSelect(array('name', 'description');